# Чи має запозичений термін “краудфандинг” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: from-english, синоніми, запозичені-слова, іншомовні-слова

Знайомлячись з ідеями, які міняють світ, [натрапив](https://inspired.com.ua/ideas/crowdfunding/) на такий термін як "*краудфандинг*". Стало цікаво, чи існують відповідники (або синоніми) українського походження.

Вікіпедія [пояснює](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) його як:

> **Громадське фінансування**, англійською **Краудфандинг** (англ. Crowdfunding, crowd — «громада, гурт, юрба», funding — «фінансування»), тобто «Фінансування громадою» — це співпраця людей, які добровільно об'єднують свої гроші чи інші ресурси разом, як правило через Інтернет, аби підтримати зусилля інших людей або організацій. Громадське фінансування може виконувати різні функції — допомога постраждалим від стихійних лих, підтримка з боку вболівальників чи фанатів, підтримка політичних кампаній, фінансування стартап-компаній та малого бізнесу, створення вільного програмного забезпечення тощо.

"Офіційний сайт Української мови" за запитом нічого [не надав](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3&t=0).

Поґуґливши знайшов ресурс українського проекту "[Спільнокошт](https://biggggidea.com/)", який є реалізацією проекту краудфандингу в Україні.

На "Словотворі" [пропонують](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kraudfandyng) наступні замінники (і до речі, використовують написання "*краудфандинґ*"):

> спільнокошт, crowdfunding, гуртокошт, гуртомкошт, складчина, гуртош.

"Український правопис" [не допоміг](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).

Отже, чи має термін “*краудфандинг*” та похідні від терміну слова, додаткові (крім наведених) відповідні синоніми та/або українські похідники?